# Using RSelenium to change the onglet on a website

Tags: r, web-scraping, rselenium

I’am using R selenium to scrape data on a web site :
https://iwas.ophardt.online/en/biography/athlete/BURDON-Renata

I need to find a solution to browse the page and go to the tab « Matches »
Here is a part of the HTML page source (I Think it’s the most important part) :

```
< div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="results">

< div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="matches">

< a href="#matches" aria-controls="results" class="nav-link" role="tab">Matches < /a>
```

Here my code :

```
library(RSelenium)

URL = "https://iwas.ophardt.online/en/biography/athlete/BURDON-Renata"

remote_driver <- driver[["client"]]

remote_driver$open() #open the navigator

remote_driver$navigate(URL) # go to the website

MATCHES = remote_driver$findElement(using = 'id', value = "results") # find the good tab

MATCHES$clickElement() #click on the good tab to change the page
```

But nothing happens !

Do you have an idea on how to go to the tab « matches »

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
library(RSelenium)

URL = 'https://iwas.ophardt.online/en/biography/athlete/BURDON-Renata'

driver <- RSelenium::rsDriver(browser = 'firefox', port = 4321L)

remote_driver <- driver[['client']]

remote_driver$open() 

remote_driver$navigate(URL) 

MATCHES = remote_driver$findElements(using = 'class', value = 'nav-link')


# Navigate to different tabs by adjusting the index in MATCHES: 
MATCHES[[8]]$clickElement()
```

Answer (score 0):

Below a possible solution.

```
#Start the library
library(RSelenium) 

#Start a selenium server and browser (you have to select it) 
driver <- rsDriver(browser=c("firefox"), port = 4567L)

#Defines the client part.
remote_driver <- driver[["client"]]

#Sent the web site address to the firefox 
remote_driver$navigate("https://iwas.ophardt.online/en/biography/athlete/BURDON-Renata")

#You can select the element through the xpath

#CLick Results
remote_driver$findElement(using = 'xpath', value = '/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a')$clickElement()

#CLick Matches
remote_driver$findElement(using = 'xpath', value = '/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[3]/a')$clickElement()

#CLick Rankings
remote_driver$findElement(using = 'xpath', value = '/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[4]/a')$clickElement()

#CLick Memberships
remote_driver$findElement(using = 'xpath', value = '/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[5]/a')$clickElement()
```